# Force an item to be on the second line using CSS, but if first item is too long, indent by wrapped text

Tags: css, css-float

I've tried many things and maybe it's not possible without JavaScript. What I want is the following. Consider two items (for example sentences, wrapped in `<span>` tags):

```
This is the first item in the list of sentences.
This is the second item.
```

If the first item contains too much text, I'd like to keep the second item on the second line, but float behind it like so.

```
This is the first item in the list of sentences, which is really long
and therefore wraps. This is the second item.
```

I've tried applying the style `white-space: nowrap;` to the second item, which works but only if the first item is long *enough*. If the first item is too short, it will look like

```
This is the first item. This is the second item.
```

Is it possible to force the second item onto the second line, but in case the first item wraps float behind it?

Edit:

There are no explicit line breaks in the first item. Only if it's too long it will be wrapped because of the window width.

Comment: Hey. Are we allowed to set limitations to the parent of these two lines? Can't you set the max-width property to the parent, like so: https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/xNepre

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to set some limitations to the parent container, this might be a solution:

```html
<div>
  <p>This is the first item. This is the second item. </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This is the first item in the list of sentences, which is really long
and therefore wraps. This is the second item. </p>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/xNepre)